# SQL Server: Insert record into a table if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-insert, exists

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have two tables. One is called `People` and the other is called `Contacting`

```
People Table
ID primary key
NAME
WEBSITE
EMAIL

Contacting Table
ID (foreign key to People ID)
WAY_OF_CONTACTING
REFERENCE
```

The logic goes as follows: For every person there is in the `People`'s table there could be several records on the `Contacting`'s Table. Obviously, the `relationship` between People and Contacting is `1:many`.

`WAY_OF_CONTACTING` could have only 2 values: *"Email"* and *"Website"* and the `REFERENCE` field contains the email or the website's name. The primary key of the `Contacting table` is a `composiste primary key` consisting of the ID and the Way_Of_Contacting. (This means, for every ID, they can only have up to **one** email and **one** website)
The records on the people's table get deleted everynight and get populated throughout the day.

4 things could happen in the People table:

1. Website and Email empty
2. Website empty but not Email
3. Email empty but not Email
4. Neither Website nor Email Empty

My problem is the following:

**For every record** in the `People` table whos `Website` field is **not empty** I want to check `if there exists` a record in `Contacting` table in which the `ID matches` and `Way_Of_Contacting='Website'`

**For every record** in the `People` table whos `Email` field is **not empty** I want to check `if there exists` a record in `Contacting` table in which the `ID matches` and `Way_Of_Contacting='Email'`

In both of these cases, if the record doesn't exist, create a record.
How could this be accomplished?
I've tried using `merge` and `if not exists` but I can't seem to find a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

> For every record in the People table whos Website field is not empty I want to check if there exists a record in Contacting table in which the ID matches and Way_Of_Contacting='Website'
>
> . . . if the record doesn't exist, create a record.

You can use `not exists` with `insert`.  The example for "website" is:

```
insert into contacting (id, way_of_contacting, reference)
    select p.id, 'Website', p.website
    from people p
    where not exists (select 1
                      from contacting c
                      where c.id = p.id and
                            c.way_of_contacting = 'Website' and
                            c.reference = p.website
                     );
```

Similar logic is used for "email".

Comment: This looks pretty great!! Will this work in the following cases?
When the ID exists in Contacting but doesn't have a Website record.
When the ID doesn't exist in Contacting

Comment: @PedroEmilioVélez . . . No.  That is not the question you asked here.  If you have a different question, ask as a *new* question.  This question now has an answer.